# Android activity transition ObjectAnimator skip to end

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I'm following this tutorial to make this activity transition: http://javatechig.com/android/using-custom-activity-transition-in-gridview-image-gallery
And everything is exactly same except I load images from local storage. I have test on Nexus 5 with 6.0 Android and have next problem if ANIMATION_DURATION is 600, it is looking like phone skip entering animation and show final state, if I change duration to 6000 there is nice smooth entering animation without any lag. Exit Animation works well in both cases.
 
Do you now what is problem?

Comment: Check if you are reading the image files on the UI thread; this could be responsible for what you are seeing.

Comment: I have removed loading image and than black background didn't fade in

Comment: Click screen during transition, does ObjectAnimator run well?